# Python thread is not alive/finished running but value is not returned yet

Tags: python, multithreading, python-multithreading

I have a class FrameThread that inherits from Thread in python

```
class FrameThread(Thread):
def __init__(self, threadID, customFunction, args):
    threading.Thread.__init__(self)
    self.threadID = threadID
    self.task = customFunction
    self.args = args
    self.output = None

def run(self):
    self.output = self.task(self.args)
```

The reason I have this class is so that once the thread finishes running my custom function (checking by calling is_alive()), I can retrieve the function returned value.

My program looks something like this

In the first block of code

```
mythread = FrameThread(threadID, myCustomFunction, args)
mythread.start()
```

In the second block of code

```
if not mythread.is_alive():
   outputVar = mythread.output
   print(outputVar)
```

This sometimes works and sometimes doesn't. The console either prints out the actual returned value of myCustomFunction or None. So I figured this might be because the value wasn't passed to mythread.output before the python runs 'outputVar = mythread.output'. So I added a loop in the second block of code just for testing.

```
if not mythread.is_alive():
   while mythread.output == None:
      print("Reee")
   outputVar = mythread.output
   print(outputVar)
```

And to my surprise, the program printed out a bunch of "Reee"s and then printed out the correct value of outputVar.

This behavior is very weird and it's probably because I did something wrong (very likely in my FrameThread class). Please let me know how I could probably fix it, or how to implement the FrameThread subclass properly.

Comment: Before "the second block of code", is there any additional code that waits for the thread to complete? Please provide a [complete example of code](https://stackoverflow.com/help/minimal-reproducible-example) that we can run, that displays the behaviour you don't understand, instead of a few fragments, which suggests you're leaving important code out.

Comment: Sorry for not providing enough details. I use openCV for this project and a lot of other custom classes so I could not find a way to fit them all in this post without overwhelming people. I tried making a simpler version of the program without all the hairy details but couldn't recreate the bug. However, I did narrow the problem down to what was said in the post, mythread.output wasn't initialized with the correct value before the second block of code run, but it did get initialized a while after (hence escaping the infinite loop in the second block of code).

Comment: I tried adding a print statement in the run() function in FrameThread class that prints out mythread.output, and another print statement in the second block of code that also print out mythread.output. The print statement in the second block of code came first displaying None while the print statement in FrameThread class came after displaying the actual value.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I've checked the code of the `threading` module and could not find why this is happening. Nevertheless, you can get rid of this problem if you `join` the thread before getting the result. You *should* anyway `join` the thread at some point. You should replace the second block of code by:

```
if not mythread.is_alive():
   mythread.join()
   outputVar = mythread.output
   print(outputVar)
```

Using `is_alive()` like this is seldom useful: it is mostly meant to check if a `join` has timed out or not. For example:

```
mythread.join(0)
if mythread.is_alive():
   # timed out
   print('Still waiting for thread to finish...')
   # do some work in the main thread...
else:
   outputVar = mythread.output
   print(outputVar)
```

I suggest that you consider using other types of synchronization or `concurrent.futures`

Comment: I tried using join() before but the error still persists. However, I did find a workaround. Instead of checking if mythread.is_alive(), I just check if mythread.output == None and make sure all the functions I pass it will return a value other than None. Thank you for confirming the expected behavior tho, and thanks for the recommendation. I will definitely look into that.